# jsx css sizing issue, possible flex conversion

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm creating a simple web page using React.
I have an outer div with an `<img />` tag and a `<div />` tag with other divs and things like that inside of it.
The `<img />` doesn't resize (so if I zoom in and out, it just stays the same size really). The `<div />` tag does (the resizing gets kind of weird when I zoom in past 90% though). 
I'm just curious as to why this is happening? There are 3 images within the `<div />` and text overlaying each image. Then the `<img />` tag is really just more of a large logo. Any advice? Beneath is the JSX

```
<div className='container'>
    <img src="logo.png" alt='Logo Large' className='logo' />
    <div className='container1'>
        <div alt='cc' className='container2'>
            <div className='cc'>
                asd
            </div>
        </div>
        <div alt='cc1' className='container3'>
            <div className='cc1'>
                asdddd
            </div>
        </div>
        <div alt='cc2' className='container4'>
            <div className='cc2'>
                123124
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Beneath this is the related CSS

```
html,
body,
#app {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #2aa9e0;
    user-select: none;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Courier New';
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 97%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: inherit;
    height: 80%;
    width: 50%;
}

.container1 .container2 {
    background-image: url("...");
    width: 628px;
    height: 324px;
    position: relative;
}

.container1 .container2 .cc {
    font-size: 52px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 15%;
}

.container1 .container3 {
    background-image: url("...");
    width: 213px;
    height: 139px;
    position: relative;
}

.container1 .container3 .cc1 {
    font-size: 52px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 30%;
}

.container1 .container4 {
    background-image: url("...");
    width: 628px;
    height: 336px;
    position: relative;
}

.container1 .container4 .cc2 {
    font-size: 52px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 15%;
}

.container .logo {
    height: 70%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I started using `flexbox` in the beginning, but kind of moved away from it to get everything properly aligned and organized in `container1`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you expect/want to happen and what is going wrong? I'm having trouble figuring out what the actual question is here. Also, it'd be helpful if you could provide a more specific example of the issue you're trying to get at--check out the guidelines on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The  `<img />` doesnt resize, since its width is set to 50% of the WIDTH of the surrounding container. The container keeps its width on zoom in/out, so the logo does as well.

If you want the logo to change its size on zoom in/out, you could use sth like:

```
.container .logo {
    width: 25em;
}
```

This way its using a width relative to pixel size (1em = 16px)